# Android 11 and .nomedia files

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-11

I have just notice that in Android 11 "directory.listFiles()" returns 0 files even with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted when a ".nomedia" file is present. But, how do File Managers show them? There should be a way to read files contained in a folder with a ".nomedia" file.

Comment: What you say does not com through.

Comment: So, is there a way to ignore .nomedia when reading files without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? And using it?

Comment: Repeat: `What you say does not com through. ` Sorry, I mean: What you say is not true. Such a file in a folder has not a single effect. Show your code that fails.

Comment: What do you mean? With targetSdkVersion 31 and compileSdkVersion 31 executed in an Android 11 phone,       

 File[] files = directory.listFiles();

shows 0 files if a .nomedia file is inside the directory and shows all files if there is no .nomedia file is inside. Same using MediaStore API

Comment: Well not here on a number of Android 11 devices. This .nomedia file now adays has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to call a MediaScannerConnection.scanFile?